# Failure of Bourns Common Mode Chokes, Series SRF2012

Tags: failure, common-mode-choke

I work for a company that designs and manufactures electromagnetic flow meters.  One component, a Bourns common mode choke, PN SRF2012-361YA, seems to have a failure rate in the field of approximately 1 per 1000.

Since the meter is already assembled and installed, the entire meter becomes inoperable.  The most common failure mode is shorting of the two coils.  It is almost impossible to exceed the rated voltage or current in the circuit application.

What is a likey failure mode of this simple electical component?

Comment: What sort of shock/vibration environment are we talking about here?

Comment: You did not state the voltage to ground value. Is there a chance of arcing? Is there surge suppression built in? Do you test in-house for possible latent failures? Do you hi-pot test these before shipping?

Comment: Are these potted or are might there be a corrosive atmosphere.  Multiple similar failures does make one suspicious about some implied or stated rating being exceeded.  Is there any chance they are hand assembled and damaged during assembly or even testing?

Answer (score 2):

SMD choke rated for 50V 0.3A must have a critical solder profile followed  exactly to prevent insulation failure

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* want to find out the root cause of the failure of the coils, I would test them before assembly and then after. I'm willing to bet that assembly is the cause of the failure, but if not then you know that the chokes are coming in bad and you can complain to the manufacturer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Assembly is not the problem since the meters go through final test and calibration, and if the choke was shorted, there would be no Vcc to power one of the boards.

Comment: The final functional test of the flow meter is not likely to ever be a stress test of the chokes. Laptop's suggestion to test the components before assembly has to be a specific test to check the chokes to stress ratings.